# Should time be categorical or continuous in a repeated measures model?

Tags: categorical-data, repeated-measures, continuous-data

What is the difference between using `time` as a categorical variable (vs continuous) in a repeated measures analysis? When is one approach preferable to the other?

Comment: Are all your data occurring at equally-spaced discrete points in time?

Comment: No, its not equally spaced.